# High Memory Allocation debugging with Apple Instruments

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I have an app written in swift which works fine initially, but throughout time the app gets sluggish.  I have opened an instruments profiling session using the Allocation and Leaks profile.

What I have found is that the allocation increases dramatically, doing something that should only overwrite the current data.

[image]

The memory in question is in the group < non-object >

[image]

Opening this group gives hundreds of different allocations, with the responsible library all being libvDSP.  So with this I can conclude it is a vDSP call that is not releasing the memory properly.  However, double clicking on any of these does not present me with any code, but the raw language I do not understand.

[image]

The function that callas vDSP is wrapped like this:

```
func outOfPlaceComplexFourierTransform(
    setup: FFTSetup,
    resultSize:Int,
    logSize: UInt,
    direction: FourierTransformDirection) -> ComplexFloatArray {

    let result = ComplexFloatArray.zeros(count:resultSize)

    self.useAsDSPSplitComplex { selfPointer in
        result.useAsDSPSplitComplex { resultPointer in
            vDSP_fft_zop(
            setup,
            &selfPointer,
            ComplexFloatArray.strideSize,
            &resultPointer,
            ComplexFloatArray.strideSize,
            logSize,
            direction.rawValue)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

This is called from another function:

```
var mags1 = ComplexFloatArray.zeros(count: measurement.windowedImpulse!.count)
    mags1 = (measurement.windowedImpulse?.outOfPlaceComplexFourierTransform(setup: fftSetup, resultSize: mags1.count, logSize: UInt(logSize), direction: ComplexFloatArray.FourierTransformDirection(rawValue: 1)!))!
```

Within this function, mags1 is manipulated and overwrites an existing array.  It was my understanding that mags1 would be deallocated once this function has finished, as it is only available inside this function.

This is the function that is called, many times per second at times.  Any help would be appreciated, as what should only take 5mb, very quickly grows by two hundred megabytes in a couple of seconds.

Any pointers to either further investigate the source of the leak, or to properly deallocate this memory once finished would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe I solved this so quickly after posting this.  (I genuinely had several hours of pulling my hair out).

Not included in my code here, I was creating a new FFTSetup every time this was called.  Obviously this is memory intensive, and it was not reusing this memory.

In instruments looking at the call tree I was able to see the function utilising this memory.

[image]